# Redirect remove query

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect this page:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/mypage/subpage/
```

To:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/tempage/index.html
```

and this is my htaccess directive:

```
Redirect  302 /mypage/subpage/ /tempage/index.html
```

This redirects correctly but it adds a query string `?url=/mypage/subpage/` at the end of the URL, how can I remove it?

Comment: show us your htaccess please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the `?` at the end on the right hand of the `RewriteRule` it will not pass the query string to the next URL:

```
RewriteRule ^mypage/subpage/$ /tempage/index.html? [R=302,L]
```

And if you want it to work for `mypage/subpage/` with and without the ending `/`, such as `mypage/subpage` then use it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^mypage/subpage/?$ /tempage/index.html? [R=302,L]
```

From HTTPD 2.4 and above you also have the `QSD` flag, which can be used like this:

```
RewriteRule ^mypage/subpage/?$ /tempage/index.html [R=302,QSD,L]
```

The `QSD` flag discard any query string attached to the incoming URI.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried your code above but it does not redirect the page. the two pages have completely different contents, so Im not sure rewrite applies to that

Comment: @JonFabian how have you changed the above to reflect the actual folders?

Comment: sorry i did not get your question

Comment: `RewriteRule ^mypage/subpage/$ /tempage/index.html? [R=302,L]` is the same as the rule you are using Redirect but converted to Rewrite, so it should work. Given that you have properly replaced `mypage/subpage/` and `/tempage/index.html` with the folders in question it should work just the same with the addition of removing the query string. However you should not start the first part `mypage/subpage/` with a slash or it will not work for example `RewriteRule ^/mypage/subpage/$ /tempage/index.html? [R=302,L]` this will fail because of the slash at the begin of left hand part of the rule.

Comment: The first URL `mypage/subpage` is actually a result from a rewritten rule and not a folder.

Comment: This is the changed code: `RewriteRule ^/learning/treatments/envirogro/?$ /envirogro/index.html? [R=302,L]`

Comment: `RewriteRule ^learning/treatments/envirogro/?$ /envirogro/index.html? [R=302,L]`

Comment: It should not start with `/` like I have mentioned above.